# angular material: Cannot read property 'openDialogs' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to write a test for a component that is using a MatDialog. But the test fails with the aforementioned error.

Here are a few more details on where the errors occurs:

> ```
>   at MatDialogTitle.Object.<anonymous>.MatDialogTitle.ngOnInit (node_modules/@angular/src/lib/dialog/dialog-content-directives.ts:91:73)
>   at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (../packages/core/src/view/provider.ts:205:15)
>   at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (../packages/core/src/view/view.ts:429:14)
> ```

I am using a proprietary Mocking-Framework which mocks components and directives. I am guessing  that I have to provide more input on those mocks in order for the MatDialog to work properly.

Can anybody give me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: Can you also give us a hint by sharing your relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it:**

I needed to provide a mock of the MatDialog-Class

```
  providers: [
    { provide: MatDialog, useClass: MockDialog },
  ],
```

with the according Mock:

```
class MockDialog {}
```

The MatDialog gets injected into the MatDialogTitle-Directive, therefore there has to be a MatDialog-Mock in the list of providers, otherwise it will be undefined.